# Memory statistic increase and not tally with run time for java

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have below 2 snapshot of my heapdump. Each take at different time. I am afraid is that I notice increase in the number of objects is this normal? What is the difference between the 3 objects, shallow heap and reatined heap?

Snapshot 1

```
Class Name                                                       |   Objects | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                 |           |              |              
java.lang.String                                                 |    29,635 |      948,320 |  >= 2,416,080
char[]                                                           |    28,722 |    2,208,984 |  >= 2,208,984
java.lang.Object                                                 |    24,001 |      384,016 |    >= 384,016
java.util.HashMap$Entry                                          |    11,077 |      354,464 |  >= 6,204,552
java.util.TreeMap$Entry                                          |    10,316 |      412,640 |    >= 416,064
java.util.TreeMap                                                |    10,143 |      486,864 |    >= 902,960
java.util.Hashtable$Entry                                        |     7,773 |      248,736 |    >= 459,944
byte[]                                                           |     7,439 |    3,345,408 |  >= 3,345,408
java.util.HashMap$Entry[]                                        |     7,323 |      641,816 |  >= 6,329,016
java.util.HashMap                                                |     7,301 |      350,448 |  >= 6,310,048
java.lang.ref.Finalizer                                          |     5,208 |      208,320 |  >= 2,970,240
java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger                        |     5,029 |       80,464 |     >= 80,488
java.io.FileDescriptor                                           |     5,007 |      120,168 |    >= 200,296
java.lang.Object[]                                               |     4,873 |      262,048 |    >= 845,856
java.net.SocksSocketImpl                                         |     4,857 |      543,984 |  >= 1,620,944
java.net.Socket                                                  |     4,856 |      155,392 |    >= 233,096
java.net.SocketInputStream                                       |     4,855 |      233,040 |    >= 498,160
java.net.Inet4Address                                            |     4,817 |      154,144 |    >= 203,600
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$BooleanConnectionProperty|     4,400 |      281,600 |    >= 281,608
java.util.ArrayList                                              |     3,700 |       88,800 |    >= 349,928
java.util.HashSet                                                |     3,415 |       54,640 |    >= 502,096
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl                                     |     3,386 |      514,672 |  >= 5,481,192
Total: 22 of 2,443 entries; 2,421 more                           |   250,175 |   14,989,928 |              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Snapshot 2

```
Class Name                                                       |   Objects | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                 |           |              |              
byte[]                                                           |     8,816 |    3,401,752 |  >= 3,401,752
char[]                                                           |    31,516 |    1,990,752 |  >= 1,990,752
java.lang.String                                                 |    32,595 |    1,043,040 |  >= 2,643,008
java.net.SocksSocketImpl                                         |     6,905 |      773,360 |  >= 2,311,056
java.util.HashMap$Entry[]                                        |     8,731 |      763,160 |  >= 7,448,192
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet                                    |     4,068 |      715,968 |  >= 5,326,728
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl                                     |     4,070 |      618,640 |  >= 6,596,656
java.util.TreeMap                                                |    12,202 |      585,696 |  >= 1,080,624
com.mysql.jdbc.Field                                             |     4,059 |      584,496 |  >= 1,071,968
java.lang.Object                                                 |    32,988 |      527,808 |    >= 527,808
java.util.TreeMap$Entry                                          |    12,346 |      493,840 |    >= 494,896
java.util.HashMap                                                |     8,709 |      418,032 |  >= 7,471,688
java.util.HashMap$Entry                                          |    12,611 |      403,552 |  >= 7,312,464
java.net.SocketInputStream                                       |     6,903 |      331,344 |    >= 710,152
java.lang.Object[]                                               |     5,592 |      302,352 |    >= 845,248
java.lang.ref.Finalizer                                          |     7,349 |      293,960 |  >= 4,300,272
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$BooleanConnectionProperty|     4,400 |      281,600 |    >= 281,608
java.util.Hashtable$Entry                                        |     8,015 |      256,480 |    >= 489,904
java.net.Socket                                                  |     6,904 |      220,928 |    >= 331,400
java.net.Inet4Address                                            |     6,861 |      219,552 |    >= 289,680
java.io.FileDescriptor                                           |     7,108 |      170,592 |    >= 284,336
com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataStatic                                     |     4,056 |      129,792 |    >= 454,272
Total: 22 of 2,446 entries; 2,424 more                           |   295,977 |   16,546,032 |              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The first snapshot shows 14.3 mb and second is 15.8mb . Where as the one I took from run time shows fluctuation. So which is the correct memory use and how to indicate any memory leak?

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
// Run the garbage collector
//runtime.gc();
// Calculate the used memory
long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
System.out.println("\n\nUsed memory is bytes: " + memory);
//Print the jvm heap size.
long heapSize = runtime.totalMemory();
System.out.println("\n\nHeap Size = " + heapSize);

int mb = 1024*1024;
System.out.println("##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####");

//Print used memory
System.out.println("Used Memory:" + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb);

//Print free memory
System.out.println("Free Memory:" + runtime.freeMemory() / mb);

//Print total available memory
System.out.println("Total Memory:" + runtime.totalMemory() / mb);

//Print Maximum available memory
System.out.println("Max Memory:" + runtime.maxMemory() / mb);
```

Comment: Two snapshots from different runs (or even a single run) proves nothing. A memory leak is when memory usage keeps increasing without bounds.

Comment: @What do you mean usage keep increasing without bounds? What will be pattern be? How do I interpret based on the object increase what does that tell me?

Comment: 1.5 MB (Mega-Bytes, not mb for milli-bits) is worth about 1.5 cents of memory, or put another way, noise.

Comment: It means the usage increase much more than this and doesn't come down after a full GC.  It is only how much is used after a full GC over time which matters.

Comment: Take many snapshots over a long runtime, smooth out the curve you'll get by plotting them against time, and look which way the resulting curve trends. Smooth it out by discarding outliers, and by replacing each point with an average of some amount N of surrounding / preceding data points. For an application in a steady state (i.e. the average actual usage of it is the same throughout) this curve should be more or less flat in the end.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I also ran the .jstat tool I notice the perm generation also show increase. There is no full GC yet. Should I wait till then. Why is my runtime fluctuating always?

Comment: @millimoose beside taking many snapshot any other mechanism to confirm is there is any leaking? Why is that my tool pointing Eclipse MAT showing to memory 36 instances of "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection", loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xf0031870" occupy 9,182,592 (55.50%) bytes. but I guess this is due to I am doing connection pooling.

Comment: You're missing the forest because of the trees. The only way to confirm your application is leaking any memory is showing it does, in fact, leak memory. And your application only leaks memory if its memory use, in a steady state, grows without bounds. That's the **definition** of a memory leak, you can't show you have one without measuring that.

Comment: Another definition would be that your program does not release memory that it only needs temporarily, but it's impossible to tell by gazing at a heap snapshot which of those objects are needed temporarily and whether or not they will ever be released.

Comment: @millimoose based on your experience what are the utilities used to measure? IS jstat a good tool to keep measurement of the generation? I just want to monitor to make sure all is ok and fine. Any recommendation.

Comment: @user2711681 My experience is that straightforward line-of-business apps that let established frameworks do the heavy lifting very rarely actually leak memory, certainly not enough to be an issue between scheduled server downtimes. Also what you need is not a tool, tools merely provide you with data. What you need is to evaluate the data properly.

Comment: @millimoose yes I am very new to this tools. What data can I evaluate properly? Any indication on those.

Comment: I feel like I'm going in circles. Just so I'm being clear: **there is no magical easy way to tell whether your application is "doing fine"**. This is an aggregate of many metrics. If you want to know how to check for memory leaks I've outlined how, and you can probably find blog posts explaining it better and with less handwaving.

Comment: @millimoose ok I will do some research further on it too.

Comment: If you want to know what your heap snapshots mean: **they mean nothing.** You don't haphazardly gather data then look what it could mean. (Okay, that's not true, there's entire businesses built on that idea, but that's not relevant to your case unless you're trying to build a server monitoring tool to sell.) You have to first decide what you want to know (what hypothesis you want to test), then find out what data is necessary for this, then gather said data. I.e. go about it exactly the other way around.

Comment: @millimoose no we are not building a monitoring tool to sell. MY hypothesis is we are want to look at memory usage? What is the trend of it? So what data is necessary for my case ?

Comment: ...I've went through all that before. You need a statistically significant set (a lot) of memory use samples (like heapdumps) taken from when your application is running in a steady state (for a while). Also that's not a hypothesis - a hypothesis would be a question with a yes/no answer. Like "does my memory usage keep growing without a bound over time?"

Comment: @millimoose thank you for understanding my condition appreciate it that you have also gone through that/. How many sample you suggest say per hour or per day ? I really would like to learn from your experiences.

Comment: @user2711681 I'm going off common sense (knowing what a memory leak is) and a basic understanding of statistics, not experience. Just go and write some code already. More data never hurts but gathering it hurts performance. I'd say you want samples in the hundreds to know anything conclusive. So for an application that runs for days at a go, one sample every 10-15 minutes should work.

Comment: Normally I take the sample over every day and I notice there is increase in the memory over every day. I will try to take more samples. So what pattern will be significant to highlight or be to be looked ? Like the sample 1 is first day is 14.3 mb and second day is 15.8mb